# MongoDB $push operator not working as expected in Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So I have a fairly simple piece of code as follows

```
db.get().collection('bars').insert({
                    barID: req.body.button,
                }, {
                    $push: {
                        usersfbID: req.body.profileUser[0].facebookID
                    }
                }, function(err, doc) {
                    if (err) {
                        throw err;
                    }
                    if (doc) {
                        console.log('Had to create a new document for this bar');
                        console.log(doc);
                        //callback(null, doc);
                    }
                });
```

So, I'm just checking to see if a document for a bar exists, and if it doesn't then I create that document. And I want to insert an array for the usersfbID field so that I can store all the users going to the bar.

However, when I run the code, I don't get an error and it says the document has inserted but when the document logs, it doesn't have the userfbID field.

So what am I doing wrong? Does the $push operator only work with the update method of db? If so, how do I insert an array for that field?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does work with the update methods

Reference > Operators > **[Update Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/)** > Array Update Operators > $push

Inserting a new entry means feeding the fields. In that case, there's no $push operation, since the array of the entry is freshly created and can be explicitly set (`usersfbID:[req.body.profileUser[0].facebookID]`, meaning that you expect several fbId for that bar). Updating an array in an element of a collection isn't an insertion, it's an update.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get that last bit. What do you mean, "No need to $push, since the array of the entry is freshly created."

Comment: sorry didn't get what you where doing at first reading. You're updating the array `usersfbID` of the `bar`. Not inserting a new entry into it.

Comment: No, I am newly creating the usersfbID of the bar. Because I am creating the document for that bar using the same function.

Answer (score 0):

So, just to provide an answer to the question I was facing.. 
Yes, you can only use $push or $addToSet with an update operation on a mongoDB document

Here is the way I implemented the code.

```
db.get().collection('bars').update({
        barID: req.body.button,
    }, {
        $addToSet: {
            usersfbID: req.body.profileUser[0].facebookID,
            usersDocID: req.body.profileUser[0]._id
        }
    }, {
        upsert: true
    }, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('There is an error here');
            throw err;
        }
        if (doc) {
            console.log('Had to create a new document for this bar');
            callback(null, doc);
        }
    });
```

> The upsert: true makes sure to insert a new document if the update method couldn't find the specified document.